# Prove it converges: $a_n=\frac{1}{1+1^2}+\frac{1}{1+2^2}+...+\frac{1}{1+n^2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$(a_n)_{n>=1}$

$a_n=\frac{1}{1+1^2}+\frac{1}{1+2^2}+...+\frac{1}{1+n^2}$

I need to prove the series converges. I am really confused by this kind of exercises, I was taught in high school that a series converges if it is monotone and bounded, nothing more, this was the only way to prove a series converges.

Now my confusion comes from the fact that there's no place on google that mentions this, instead there seems to be a couple of 'tests' to help decide whether a series converges or diverges.

How do I apply the 'highschool method' to solve this exercise? More specifically how do I prove it is bounded, cause it is clearly increasing(right?).

Do I just take the limit of $\frac{1}{1+n^2}$ and that is the upper bound while the lower bound would be the first term$(\frac{1}{2})$?

Comment: Well, you can see that each of the terms is smaller than $\frac{1}{k^2}$... for ex.
$$
\frac{1}{1+2^2} < \frac{1}{2^2}
$$

Comment: Oh, I feel like a fool now, this was too easy.

Comment: The typical way to check for monotone is looking at $a_{n+1} - a_{n}$.

Comment: That is what I am usually doing, or if that is not working I would look at $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$

Comment: Maybe you are also interested in the value of the infinite sum. It is $\frac{1}{2} (\pi  \coth (\pi )-1) \simeq 1.07667 $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{1+k^2}<\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{k^2}=\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Therefore, it converges.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out,
$$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{1+k^2}<\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k^2}$$

But does $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k^2}$ converge?

Notice that $\forall{k\in{\mathbb{N}}},\;\text{we have}$
$$\frac{1}{k^2}\le\frac{1}{k(k-1)}=\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k}$$
Now,
$$\sum_{k=2}^{n}(\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k})$$ is a telescoping series, and 
$$\sum_{k=2}^{n}(\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k})=1-\frac{1}{n+1}\le1$$

So 
$$\sum_{k=2}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k^2}\le\sum_{k=2}^{n}(\dfrac{1}{k-1}-\dfrac{1}{k})=1-\frac{1}{n+1}\le1$$

Note the first summation starts from $k=2$ instead of $k=1$.

However, when $k=1,\; \dfrac{1}{k^2}=1$.

Therefore,
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{1+k^2}\lt\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k^2}\le 1+\sum_{k=2}^{n}(\frac{1}{k-1}-\dfrac{1}{k})=2-\dfrac{1}{n+1}\le 2$$

Since $\forall{k}\;\text{such that}\;1\le k\le n,\;\dfrac{1}{1+k^2}\gt 0$, the series is increasing, i.e. $\forall{N\gt n},\;$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{N}\dfrac{1}{1+k^2}\gt\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{1+k^2}$$

Recalling that the series $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{1+k^2}$ is bounded above, it then follows that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{1+k^2}$$ converges. Similarly, $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k^2}$$
also converges.

Comment: That's a great solution. I appreciate you.

Answer (score 0):

As $$\frac{1}{1+k^2}< \frac{1}{k^2} \implies \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+k^2} < \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Comment: The $"n"$ should be tends to infinity

Comment: Oh! yes you are right.